# Обновление файлов созданных моим приложением

Tags: java, android, файлы

Файлы создаваемые моим приложением с компьютера по USB сразу не видны. Эта проблема решается либо перезагрузкой телефона (что меня не устраивает), либо вот таким кодом в методе:

```
public void visualfile() {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
        new String[]{sdFile.toString()}, null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                // mediaScannerConnection.disconnect();
            }
        });
}
```

И всё просто чудесно - файл обновляется(?) и сразу виден через usb если метод применяется лишь к одному файлу.  Но у меня идёт целый ряд файлов генерируемые через определённые промежутки времени в очень сложном порядке и задачи их имён. А с учётом моей малограмотности и величиной сделанного кода применить этот метод к каждому по отдельности (что логично) - у меня никак не получается. Есть ли какой-то способ обновить(?) сразу всё содержимое папки без применения мудрёных циклов? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

После сохранения файла, вызывайте следующий код:

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
File file = new File(path);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```